# invoke between stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure **tst_student_sp** which executes insert command.After that insertion I need to insert same details in another table which has a different stored procedure **tst_user_sp** already written.When I am trying to call **tst_user_sp**, it is not working.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[tst_student_sp] 
    @gid nvarchar(64)= null,
    @student_firstname nvarchar(45) =null,
    @student_lastname nvarchar(45) =null,
    @dateof_birth datetime =null,
    @dateof_join datetime =null,
    @case_id integer =null,
    @result int output
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
if @case_id=1
    if @gid != ''
        BEGIN
            insert into tst_student(
            student_gid,
            student_firstname,
            student_lastname,
            dob,
            doj
            )values(
            @gid,
            @student_firstname,
            @student_lastname,
            @dateof_birth,
            @dateof_join)

            set @result=@@rowcount
            if @result=1
                BEGIN
                    EXEC dbo.tst_user_sp '4',@student_firstname,@student_lastname,'vcx102','s',2;                   
                END
        END
```

The second stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[tst_user_sp]     
    @user_gid nvarchar(64)=null,
    @fname nvarchar(45)=null,
    @lname nvarchar(45)=null,
    @user_id nvarchar(64) = null, 
    @pwd nvarchar(64) = null,   
    @class_gid nvarchar(64)=null,
    @case_id integer=null   
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF @case_id=2
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tst_user (user_gid,user_firstname,user_lastname,user_id,user_pwd,state)
    values (@user_gid,@fname,@lname,@user_id,@pwd,'Active')
    print @@rowcount
END
```

This part of coding is not executing.The table remains empty.

```
set @result=@@rowcount
if @result=1
    BEGIN
        EXEC dbo.tst_user_sp '4',@student_firstname,@student_lastname,'vcx102','s',2;                   
    END
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) When you want assistance with a problem, it's very helpful to provide information about the kind of behaviour you're expecting, and the one you're getting. I assume in your case, you expected a row to be inserted into `tst_user`, and that didn't happen, with no error message etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing one parameter, so `@case_id` ends up being `null`. `null` isn't `2`, so there's no insert.

Don't use default parameter values if you *don't expect them to work*. The more constraints, the less possibility of an error like this. Out of all the parameters it doesn't look like you expect *any* of them to be missing. So remove those defaults.

Oh, and `'whatever'` is a `varchar` constant - for `nvarchar`, you want to use `N'whatever'`. Not a big difference here, but it can cause you to miss indices and, well, non-local characters :)

Also, be careful about `@@rowcount`. I wouldn't use it unless you need it (not this case) and understand well how it works - it's very tricky using it with triggers, for example. Even a simple `set` assignment will cause `@@rowcount` to change to `1`. And reading `@@rowcount` will reset it to `0`. Careful :)

Comment: @SenthilKumarJ Did this answer solved your problem? If yes, then please accept this as answer.